# Unzip files in phone from ADB terminal

Tags: android, zip, adb, busybox

I am trying to unzip files in my android (11) phone with ADB from the terminal (Ubuntu 20.04). I need to run a script from my Ubuntu laptop to unzip files on my phone.

I have already tried [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en&gl=US) from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18711/how-to-extract-zip-through-adb-shell?newreg=3e71607263a44f1a98bba47073a1b22e) suggestion. With this app, I can unzip files after accessing the shell. I mean -

```
$ adb shell                
a60q:/ $ cd /sdcard/
a60q:/sdcard $ unzip data.zip                                            
Archive:  data.zip
  inflating: Screenshot from 2020-11-30 16-45-46 (7th copy).png
  inflating: Screenshot from 2020-11-30 16-45-46 (10th copy).png
```

But when I try to use the direct command, it shows an error.

```
$ adb shell unzip /sdcard/data.zip
unzip: couldn't create file Screenshot from 2020-11-30 16-45-46 (7th copy).png: Read-only file system
Archive:  /sdcard/data.zip
```

Rooting phone isn't an option. My questions are -

1. What can I do here to unzip from the terminal?
2. Is there any tool to make compressed zip files (in Android) from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to successfully invoke the `unzip` command from the terminal you should explicitly specify the folder where the zip's content will be extracted, for instance:

```
adb shell unzip /sdcard/data.zip -d /sdcard
```

By invoking `unzip --help` you will get more information on the other parameters available as well.